# Automate pressing enter key inside of bash script

Tags: bash

I have a Bash script where I try to wget a repo for which I have to press enter for a very long Eula text, literally I have to manually press enter key 20+ times and then type yes. Can someone please help me to automate pressing enter key and at the end enter yes in bash script.

```
yes "" | command
```

and

```
echo -ne '\n' | <command>
```

doesn't work for me, I still have to manually press enter key.

Here is the code, so when it runs wget, I need to keep pressing enter till it ask if you want to accept the license and there I enter "yes".

```
#!/bin/bash

pid=$(ps aux | grep xxx-server |grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}')
if [ -n "$pid" ]; then
    kill $pid
    echo -e  "\n$pid killed -Success"
fi
# Check if the package already installed then remove it

if [ `dpkg -l | grep xxx-server  | wc -l` -gt "0"  ]
then
    apt-get -y remove  xxx-server
fi
# wget the repo using silent install
if [ "apt-cache search xxx-server" ];then
#if [ $? != 0 ] ; then
        echo -e  "\nremoving repo ...."
        #aptitude install $i -y > /dev/null
         apt-get purge xxx-server-repo-* -y  > /dev/null
         echo -e  "\nInstalling Reop .........."

 yes "" | wget -q -O - http://xxx-server.com/ | sh

fi
```

Comment: is it https or http ?

Comment: Technically, you could adapt the EULA part of the script on the fly before you pipe it into sh so that it doesn't even ask you to press a key.

Comment: @Adrian, How do I adapt the EULA part of the script on the fly? Can you please post the example

Comment: sed/awk/perl/... You need to show us the URL/code in question. But unless it's easily "fixable" you will want to use expect (see @AleksDaniels answer).

Answer (score 7):

I don't know what are you trying to do, you'd better show us some code!
But most probably you want to use expect:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn "yourscript"

for {set i 0} {$i < 20} {incr i 1} {
    send "\n"
}
send "yes\n"
```

Answer (score 4):

Even though the question is pretty old. This answer might help someone.

you can use this to supply input to your scripts.

```
cat <(echo "yes") | "Your_Command"
```

Comment: this is amazingly usefull but key in mind, enter seems to be `cat <(echo "") | <command>`

Comment: god damn...everyone should know this. THank you